# How to use get variables in htaccess (different order)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am learning PHP and HTACCESS atm.

I have a problem where i use 4 different GET variables. x,y,z,w.

I need to create an URL structure which both can be.

mysite.com/x/y

but also

mysite.com/x/z

and different other combinations.

I

I have tried this in HTACCESS, but it only work if its the same kind of structure, and not with other combnations:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?x=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?x=$1&y=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?x=$1&y=$2&z=$3&w=$4 [L]
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a 'catch-all' `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1` and then explode the `$_GET['url']` on `/` to retrieve one or more variables? It would allow you flexibility, to e.g. set `controller/action/param1/param2/...etc.` or in your case `x`, or `x` and `y`... as many parameters as you want.

Comment: Maybe :-) Thanks, will try.

Comment: Then how would you show different pages for different .php files. x should show php1.php, y php2.php and so on. The redirect working, but showing index.php for all parameters.

Comment: Your application, on evey new request for a page, will now always cycle through `index.php`, so this is where you'd 'route' to the correct page, based on what is set in query string variable `url`. E.g. if you use: `mysite.com/contact` or `mysite.com/home`, your 'router'(`index.php`) will go and `require` or `include` the correct page, i.e. `contact.php` or `home.php` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Specify [QSA] (Query string append) so you may pass a query string after your url.

Sample Code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^book/([^/]*)\.html$ book.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```